# Is there a way I can make JavaScript choose plus or minus operator?

Tags: javascript, operators

I want my JavaScript to be able to choose randomly to either subtract using the `-` operator or add using the `+` operator. Is there anyway I can make it randomly choose between the two?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried putting them into an array like this `var operator = ["+", "-"];` then making it choose a random number as to get it randomly like this. `var x = 5; var y = 20; var answer = x Math.floor(Math.random() *1) y; alert("The answer is " + answer + ".");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

get a random number

`Math.random();`

If the random number is less than 0.5, multiply by -1, else do nothing.

Comment: multiplying by -1 will negate the number, not subtract from another.  Also, please consider adding a code snippet to further exhibit your point.

Comment: I don't need to teach arithmetic here. Multiplying by negative 1 does the job when wanting to switch an addition, to a subtraction

Comment: The problem is an unclear referent.  All you have to do to clarify this is to specify what number you're applying the -1 multiplication to.  What number is he multiplying?  These kinds of things can be confusing to those who might ask themselves this question.

Comment: @kondrak - You can do `a + (b * -1)` to turn an addition into a subtraction.

Comment: @jfriend00 I know, I was just asking Chizzle to clarify what he was referring to.

Answer (score 2):

As @Chizzle said, the way to go is Math.random(), but if you want to be a bit more precise, you should use:

```
Math.random() <= 0.5
```

This way the chance is 50 to 50, and the interval could be described by [0,0.5) and [0.5,1). Math.random() returns a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).

Here is a simple code snippet with a function:

```js
function randSumSub(a, b) {
  if (Math.random() <= 0.5) {
    result = a - b;
  } else {
    result = a + b;
  }
  return result;
}
```

```css
#result {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
2 +|- 5
<button onclick="document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = randSumSub(2,5);">=</button> 
<div id="result">?</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
function getSignMultiplier() {
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
var numbers = [
  5 * getSignMultiplier(),
  5 * getSignMultiplier(),
  5 * getSignMultiplier()
];

document.getElementById('output').innerText = numbers.join(', ');
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2snbgyw2/1/

Comment: Whoops, bit late but maybe it's still useful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the inline syntax with the Math.random() trick that others have mentioned:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var a_plusOrMinus_b = (Math.random()<=0.5 ? a+b : a-b);

alert(a_plusOrMinus_b);
```